# Remove category base from URL on multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, categories, radix

I have removed the category base before, by setting the category base to '.' in  Settings » Permalinks. But ever since I installed my multisite, this option gives me 404 errors on the category pages. I suspect the changes were made by the rules I added in wp-config.php and .htaccess file when I setup my multisite. I’d love to hear if there is a rule that I can change that will fix this.

I have temporarily set the category base to 'category' again because otherwise my menu doesn't work.

NOTE: My post URLs are perfect (structure: domain/%category%/%postname%/), but the CATEGORY URLs still have 'category' in the URL and if I use the trick I described above, I get 404 errors.

EXAMPLE: https://onceuponajrny.com/destinations/asia/  = 404 error, but https://onceuponajrny.com/category/destinations/asia/  works (even when I removed the category base, as described above)

Rules I added for multisite:

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'onceuponajrny.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you add your wp-config and htaccess in your question, it will be easier to help you

Comment: Done! The top code added to wp-config, the rules from "RewriteEngine On" added to htaccess

Comment: I also just learned both onceuponajrny.com/destinations and onceuponajrny.com/category/destinations work on my website?